# How to send analog data using FM/FM Telemetry

Tags: rf, analog, antenna, frequency-modulation, vco

I am measuring the strain a bicyclist is placing on a bicycle crank arm throughout riding, using strain gages. I would like to send this data (after amplification) off of the bicycle crank arm and to my data processing unit. How can I send the analog output voltage data I am interested in measuring using an FM/FM telemetry scheme. I have looked into VCOs to create my carrier frequency, but does FM/FM require a sine wave output instead of a square wave? Also, how do I then create subcarriers frequencies so I can send multiple streams of data in parallel? Lastly, how do you take these signals and send them off? What is used to create an antenna? Theres a lot out on the internet on the overall flow of how FM/FM works, but nothing in terms of specific electrical components to use.

Comment: Why do you want to send an analogue value using analogue telemetry?

Comment: do to the size constraints of the amount of room we have for a circuit to be mounted n the rotating crank arm of a bicycle while in use, including MCU, ADC, Amplification circuits, etc. is getting large by potentially cutting out MCU and ADC we may be able to save on circuit space

Comment: For a small size circuit you can't beat a 2.4 GHz digital radio microcontroller. Processor, analogue to digital converters, microamps consumption, and all the RF stuff, and at a frequency where tiny antennas are possible. All for $2 or $3. Bonus, if you choose a BLE chip, you can easily talk to a smartphone or computer.

Comment: For an all-analogue solution, make an audio oscillator with frequency based on your strain gauge, and use this tone to amplitude modulate a small SAW oscillator module, perhaps at 433 MHz.

Comment: That is small; there are plenty of 3mm x 3mm MCUs which include the ADC, the Freescale KL03 (random choice) is in a 2 x 1.61 x 0.56mm package. However, you may find that power is also an issue. The ability to compress data, switch off the radio for short periods, and change its behaviour via firm-ware updates may become important. Small digital radio's seem to have a lot of advantages anyway. If it is part of the original bicycle, and not an add on, couldn't you use slip rings to power the device, and get the data out without radio? I'd be tempted to try Infrared if it's a few centimetres

Comment: We had met with engineers who work for a bike company and they had recommended against using slip rings. They have done a lot of data collection in house using static loads on the crank arm, but never attempted to collect the data while the bicycle was in use.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at an already existing transmitter module like the RFM02 (e.g.: www.farnell.com/datasheets/1303077.pdf). Creating your own VCO based circuit will be much more time consuming and expensive than to use a widely known solution.

Comment: So looking at the data sheet, it looks like the RFM02 requires the data to be digitized, I am looking for a way to send the data still in its analog form. How could this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution is to sample the analogue data and convert to digital as near to the sensor as practical. Partly because it is much easier to make a digital signal robust to degradation, and partly because digital transmission technology, which will move data quickly, at high-fidelity is relatively cheap. For example Bluetooth, or WiFi.

Modern MCU's with built in 12 to 16bit Analogue to Digital Converters (ADCs) are relatively low-cost (maybe under $12 for a development board?). IMHO achieving that sort of signal to noise ratio with analogue transmission technology may be much more expensive and difficult.

Finally, your data processing technology is likely digital, in which case sending digital data is a benefit, and not a weakness.